# Django 1.7 migrations: how to handle unbound methods?

Tags: django, migration, django-1.7

I'm working on a django 1.6 project running on python 2.7 and we're about to upgrade to 1.7 and utilize the new [migration tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/).

The migration system seems unable to handle unbound methods in [python 2.7 and poorly in 3.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#serializing-values) ei:

```
class Foo(models.model):
    ...

    def unbound_method_bar(self):
        ...
        return foobar
```

The documentation recommends us to just move the methods from the class to the module. Ei:

```
def unbound_method_bar(foo):
    ...
    return foobar

class Foo(models.model):
    ...
```

This approach is not great for us since the methods we've added to the model classes manily consists of utility functions used in templates.

What is the best way to tackle this? A wrapper class? A factory which dynamically add the utility methods to the model class instance? Or...?

Comment: How is that an unbound method? Seems just like a normal method to me. It only becomes unbound if you refer to it within the class, or from outside if you refer to it via the Foo class itself.

Comment: What is it that you're using the method to return? Is it something that requires an instance (i.e., could you use a `@staticmethod`?), or is it truly just a helper? Also, what model field argument are you using it for (e.g., `choices=unbound_method_bar`)?